# Compare 2 weeks data from this year to 2 weeks data last year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Imagine a simple parameterized query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE
```

This is useful for seeing data from today, yesterday, one week data and one year data. Now I am required to compare 2 weeks data of this week compared to last year. For example, today is the 30th of August. I have to compare 16-29 Aug 2021 data to 16-29 Aug 2020 data. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Try `Union all` ? [Union all](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-union-queries-in-google-bigquery/)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  "Compare" is not a SQL operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the results using `or`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.date BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE OR
      t.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(@DS_START_DATE, INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AND DATE_ADD(@DS_END_DATE, INTERVAL -1 YEAR);
```

One caution is that the comparison periods might be off if they include leap days.  Your question doesn't specify how to handle that.